# Spring data : How to get data from Multiple Mongo collections

Tags: spring-boot

I have a requirement to get from multiple mongo collections.
Ex:
Collection1:
{
"company" : "ABC",
"person" : name1
}
{
"company" : "ABC",
"person" : name2
}

Collection2:
{
"company" : "ABC",
"person" : name3
}
{
"company" : "ABC",
"person" : name4
}

The expecting output

{
"company" : "ABC",
"person" : name1
}
{
"company" : "ABC",
"person" : name2
}

{
"company" : "ABC",
"person" : name3
}
{
"company" : "ABC",
"person" : name4
}

List of collections  will be change n runtime. It will be 2 or 3 or x number of collections, I need to combine

Can you please help me  , how to get this output in Springboot using  Mongo Template

Comment: `@Document(collection = "Collection1") public class Collection1 {}`

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean ?

Comment: have your java class maps to each collection's document, I can  post on how to query them but all the resources should be out there.

Comment: Pleas post the query to combine two  collections like union